# Viewport material view

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, 3d-view

I'm wondering why viewport material shading would draw an image texture fine, but doesn't seem to be able to draw a procedural texture:

[image]
[image]

The same is true for texture shading. Is it possible to get procedural textures drawn in the viewport without having to render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

This is because the procedural texture is actually calculated by the render engine. The closest you can get is by "caching" the texture to a conventional raster image via texture baking, then using that as you would any other image texture.