# Can you see any material on a mesh without rendering?

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view

I have an eyeball material with two blend type textures and one cloud type texture but I can't see it unless I render. Is there a way to view it in the 3D view without rendering?

Comment: You could try to use Material shading mode, but it's somewhat limited. Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26604/viewport-material-view

Comment: Yeah I'm on that mode but it doesn't help much. I just like to see everything without having to render, your link helps.

Comment: What  rendering engine are you working on?

Comment: Blender render.

Comment: Is your eyeball UV Mapped?

Comment: Yes, it is UV mapped.